# How to merge two stats by in Splunk?

Tags: statistics, splunk, splunk-query

I wanted a single graph to show values.
One search is

```
index="cumu_open_csv"  Assignee="ram"
| eval open_field=if(in(Status,"Open","Reopened","Waiting","In Progress"), 1,0)
| stats count(eval(open_field=1)) AS Open, count(eval(open_field=0)) AS closed by CW_Created
```

this gives me a table as

[image: OpenCloseTable]

Similarly I have another search

```
 index="cumu_open_csv"  Assignee="ram"
| eval open_field=if(in(Status,"Open","Reopened","Waiting","In Progress"), 1,0)
| stats count(eval(open_field=1)) As DueOpen by CW_DueDate
```

which gives me another table as

[image: DUeDatetable]

I tried to combine these two using appendcols, but the X-axis has only the CW_Created and displays the second table details in wrong CW.

I wanted CW_Created and CW_Duedate to be combined and provide the result in a single table like CW, Open,Close,DueCount wherever DueCount is not for a particular CW fill it with 0, for others display the data like so.

```
CW      |Open     |Close    |DueCount
CW27    |7        |0        |0
CW28    |2        |0        |0
CW29    |0        |0        |4
CW30    |0        |7        |3
CW31    |0        |0        |1
CW32    |0        |0        |1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appendcols command is a bit tricky to use.  Events from the main search and subsearch are paired on a one-to-one basis without regard to any field value.  This means event CW27 will be matched with CW29, CW28 with CW30, and so on.

Try the append command, instead.  The results of the subsearch will follow the results of the main search, but a stats command can be used to merge them.

```
index="cumu_open_csv"  Assignee="ram"
| eval open_field=if(in(Status,"Open","Reopened","Waiting","In Progress"), 1,0)
| stats count(eval(open_field=1)) AS Open, count(eval(open_field=0)) AS closed by CW_Created
| append [ index="cumu_open_csv"  Assignee="ram"
| eval open_field=if(in(Status,"Open","Reopened","Waiting","In Progress"), 1,0)
| stats count(eval(open_field=1)) As DueOpen by CW_DueDate ]
| eval CW = coalesce(CW_Created, CW_DueDate)
| stats values(*) as * by CW
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for

```
index="cumu_open_csv"  Assignee="ram"
| eval open_field=if(in(Status,"Open","Reopened","Waiting","In Progress"), 1,0)
| stats count(eval(open_field=1)) AS Open, count(eval(open_field=0)) AS closed by CW_Created
| rename CW_Created as CW
| join type=outer CW
    [| search index="cumu_open_csv"  Assignee="ram"
    | eval open_field=if(in(Status,"Open","Reopened","Waiting","In Progress"), 1,0)
    | stats count(eval(open_field=1)) As DueOpen by CW_DueDate
    | rename CW_DueDate as CW ]
```

Or possibly this:

```
index="cumu_open_csv"  Assignee="ram"
| eval open_field=if(in(Status,"Open","Reopened","Waiting","In Progress"), 1,0)
| eval CW=if(len(CW_Created)>1,CW_Created,CW_DueDate)
| stats count(eval(open_field=1)) AS Open, count(eval(open_field=0)) AS closed, count(eval(open_field=1)) as DueOpen by CW
```

Sample data would make this *substantially* easier to try to help you with

Comment: this again gave in xaxis only the CW_Creaed...CW27, 28 and CW30 only are coming